# in LWC Create a text box on child and button on parent whenever click on that button get child value and reflect on parent?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-events

childCompoLWC

```
<template>
  <lightning-card>
    Enter value:- <lightning-input type="text" value={strInput} onchange={handleChange}> 
  </lightning-input>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

childCompoLWC.JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ChildCompoLWC3 extends LightningElement {

strInput;

handleChange(event){
    this.strInput = event.target.value;
   }
  }
```

parentCompoLWC

```
  <template>
     <lightning-card>
      <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <c-child-compo-l-w-c-3></c-child-compo-l-w-c-3>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Pass to Parent" onclick={PassToParent}> 
      </lightning-button>
       </div>
     </lightning-card>
   </template>
```

parentCompoLWC.JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few ways to pass value from child to Parent:-

1. Fire a **custom event** with payload from child and handle it in parent
2. expose an **public property** in child and access it directly using **querySelector**

In your case, you can go for second approach, a sample code would be below:-

Step 1:- define public property in child

```
@api strInput;
```

step 2:- handle the button click as below:-

```
PassToParent(){
   let childtextboxvalue = this.template.querySelector('c-child-compo-l-w-c-3').strInput;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sanketkumar.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by calling a method of child component from parent lwc -

parent -

```
HTML - 

<c-child-compo-l-w-c-3 onsendtextboxvalue={handleValue}></c-child-compo-l-w-c-3>

JS - 

PassToParent() {
        this.template.querySelector('c-child-compo-l-w-c-3').sendTextBoxValue();
    }
    
handleValue(event){
 let textBoxValue = event.detail;
}
```

child -

```
JS - 
    @api sendTextBoxValue(){
            const selectEvent = new CustomEvent('sendtextboxvalue', {
                detail: this.strInput
            });
           this.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @MukulMahawariya.